How to get the last page of API pagination
Im on react native development which has a feature flatlist scroll. i was succeed to consume the api with pagination, but im stuck how to get the latest page in pagination with this API data.
I got the response like this, i was able to catch the next page from page 1 to 10000 ( next page -> next page -> blablabla  )
but, the page 1 is the oldest data not the newest so i need to reverse the logic. like from page 10000 to 1 ( next page -> next page -> blablabla  )
I mean like:
https://censored.xxx/withpagination/page[number]=10 to https://censored.xxx/withpagination/page[number]=9 to
https://censored.xxx/withpagination/page[number]=8 and so on...
I used this ( links.next )
"links":{
    "self":"https://api.hackerone.com/v1/hackers/me/reports?page%5Bnumber%5D=1\u0026page%5Bsize%5D=100",
    "prev":"https://api.hackerone.com/v1/hackers/me/reports? like **page** page%5Bnumber%5D=0\u0026page%5Bsize%5D=100",
    "next":"https://api.hackerone.com/v1/hackers/me/reports?page%5Bnumber%5D=2\u0026page%5Bsize%5D=100"
}

This is my full code:
const initialPage = `https://censored.xxx/withpagination/`;  
  
  /** set and get modal and then call in the button  **/
  const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);
  const [nextPage, setNextPage] = useState('');

  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();

  const fetchReportsList = async (url: string) => {
      if (isLoading) {
        return;
      }

      setIsLoading(true);
      fetch(url, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
              "Authorization": "Basic <bearer-token>",
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
      })
      .then( res => res.json() )
      .then( res => {

        setData((existingItems) => {
          return [...existingItems, ...res.data];
        });

        setNextPage(res.links.next);
        setIsLoading(false);
        
      }).catch((error => {
        console.log("Error, error", error);
      }));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchReportsList(initialPage);
  }, []);

How to i get there?
How to resolve this logic, reverse this logic of pagination flatlist

wait a min, If the first page has older data, you never know the page number with new data right?

yes, so it must to write the code dynamically to get the new data from page[number]=

my code automatically fetch page[number]=1 and so on...

I WOULD NOT recommend this method. it costs you a lot of network calls

Actually it's fine with this method, because the data will not reach more than 10000 within a period of time 3 years.

Any suggestion with other method? or maybe you can help me with this method?

In your FlatList component's renderItem function, access the data array in reverse order to display the latest data first. You can use methods like data.slice().reverse() to create a reversed copy of the data array
`
<FlatList
 data={data.slice().reverse()}
 renderItem={this.renderItem}
/>

`

That's not what i mean. it's sorting the content of page[number] array not the page[number]= data
i want to fetch the last page[number]= like this
https://censored.xxx/withpagination/page[number]=10 https://censored.xxx/withpagination/page[number]=9 https://censored.xxx/withpagination/page[number]=8
